# Correlation between two hypergeometric random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

An urn contains $90$ marbles, of which there are $20$ green and $70$ non-green marbles. Tom picks $10$ marbles without replacement. For the remaining $80$ marbles, Jerry also picks $10$ marbles from the urn.

Let $X$ = # of green marbles Tom gets, and $Y$ = # of green marbles Jerry gets. What are the values for $Corr(X,Y)$ and $Cov(X,Y)$?

I'm confused about how to relate these two random variables together.
I already got the following information.

$$E(X) = \frac{20}{9}$$
$$E(X^2) = \frac{20}{9} + 90\times\left(\frac{20}{90}\times\frac{19}{89}\right)$$

But could someone provide hints about how to think about the problem for another random variable $Y$? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of the joint distribution. 
What is the probability $ P(X=x, Y=y) $ for different $x, y$ ? 
For example, for $x,y$ such that $x+y \gt 20$ the probability will always be zero.

Also note the identity of conditional probability $P(x, y) = P(y | x)P(x)$

You can then use this distribution to find both the [marginal distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_distribution#:%7E:text=Marginal%20probability%20mass%20function%5Bedit%5D), which will help you find the correlation and covariance.

Comment: I understand. So E(X) and E(Y) should be the same. E(X^2) and E(Y^2) are also the same. And E(XY) should be 10 * (20/90) * (19/89). Am I correct?

Comment: Yes correct. Except, E(XY) would be $100 \times (20/90) \times (19/89)$